# Stop event propagation from component to component React

Tags: reactjs

I'm having problem with event propagation when i don't need it. Namely from changing the number in input field of modal, it should not propagate down to another component rather it should stay contained.

```
export default class SettingsDialog extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      open: false,
      submittable: false,
      isSilent: false,
      forwardNumber: '',
      errorForwardNumber: ''
    }

    this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this)
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this)
    this.handleForwardNumberChange = this.handleForwardNumberChange.bind(this)
    this.handleIsSilentToggle = this.handleIsSilentToggle.bind(this)
  }

  //Validation Ommited

  handleForwardNumberChange(event, value) {
    const validation = this.validateNumber(value)
    this.setState({
      forwardNumber: value,
      errorForwardNumber: validation.error,
      submittable: validation.valid
    })
  }


  //Ommited

  render() {
    const actions = [
      <FlatButton label="Cancel" primary={true} onTouchTap={this.handleClose} />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Submit"
        primary={true}
        disabled={!this.state.submittable}
        onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
      />
    ]

    return (
      <div>
        <RaisedButton label="Settings" onTouchTap={this.handleOpen} />
        <Dialog
          title="Settings dialog"
          actions={actions}
          modal={true}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
        >
          <TextField
            hintText="Enter a forwarding number"
            errorText={this.state.errorForwardNumber}
            fullWidth={true}
            floatingLabelText="Forwarding number"
            floatingLabelStyle={{ color: '#522560' }}
            defaultValue={this.state.forwardNumber}
            onChange={this.handleForwardNumberChange}
          />
          <br />
          <Toggle
            label="Silent"
            onToggle={this.handleIsSilentToggle}
            style={{
              toggle: {
                marginBottom: 16
              }
            }}
          />
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop propagating the event by using [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation)

```
  handleForwardNumberChange(event, value) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // add this
    const validation = this.validateNumber(value)
    this.setState({
      forwardNumber: value,
      errorForwardNumber: validation.error,
      submittable: validation.valid
    })
  }
```

Comment: Not working still, when i change input of modal it reflects on another place.

Comment: I did try both. That was the first thing i did try. No avail it propagates.

Comment: Can you provide more info, how is the other place getting the data, is there any state? If possible paste that piece of code